# Serverside HTML rendering and client binding strategi to avoid repeating

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

For example I have this razor view

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{               

    <a href="@Item.Id">Hello world</a>
}
```

And on the client side I have this little template for binding data.

```
    var target = target.find("tbody");
    var markup = "<a href='${Id}'>Hello world<a>";

    $.template("tmpl", markup);
    var elm = $.tmpl("data", data);
```

This view contain ASP.NET Razor Syntax. But often I have a scenario where the same viewmodels could be feath by an AJAX Request and binded to DOM by some Javascript based templateing, like Knockout or jQuert template, CanJS or whatever.

I'm not so comfortable to repeat myself, as I have to do. So what are your strategies? I don't see it as an option to use only clientside as it would affect my SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could make the entire repeatable (`@foreach`) section a partial view so that the controller when called via ajax would just take the rendered partial view and push into the page.

You can tell your ajax calls that the expected content type returned would be html.

So in your controller action or a different action for ajax how ever you want to break it apart:

```
if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()) return Partial('myForeach',model);
```

That solution makes for zero repetition. The ajax call is fetching the fully rendered html that would be where the `@foreach` is.

That would be the most straightforward to ensure robots would only see a properly rendered page. (this assumes that the robots you are concerned about don't attempt to find out what the page would look like post-javascript adjustments).